# Importing from different points in python package (flask project)

Tags: python, namespaces, flask, package, python-import

I'm trying to build my first web app in flask, and I'm running into some problem. The flask app pushes some pickled objects to a redis queue. The objects are in the namespace app.mypackage.mymoduleA. That is, the objects have

```
object.__class__ == app.mypackage.mymoduleA.Myclass
```

Next, I have an external process running a daemon (located in a different module in the same package) that processes the objects as they appear in the redis queue (that is, asynchronously). My problem is that when the objects are unpickled, the pickle module throws an ImportError exception because app.mypackage.mymoduleA.Myclass is not imported into the module.

Although I understand the idea of namespaces (at least I think I do), I'm having some difficulties understanding how they work in reality. So anyway, here are my questions:

1) Is it possible to "fake" the namespace? Something like

```
import mymoduleA.Myclass as app.mypackage.mymoduleA.Myclass
```

2) Since faking namespaces is probably a hack, is there a "right" way to do this? Essentially the problem is that the objects are created and pickled in one program which import Myclass like so:

```
from mypackage.mymoduleA import Myclass
```

while they are unpickled in another program where Myclass is imported like this:

```
from mymoduleA import Myclass
```

I had some difficulties explaining what I mean, so I hope my questions make sense.

Thank you!

Bonus question: I know that the syntax in question 1 doesn't work, but could someone explain to me why this way of importing modules is not allowed?

Comment: Are you obligated to use pickle? Maybe you could dump the useful informations stored in the object, and then create a new instance in your deamon with the informations dumped.

Comment: That's a good idea, and it definitely solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'd still be grateful for answers concerning the use of namespaces.